# trying to map a set of results in react js but it's not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm  trying to build a youtube using react and youtube v3 API after using axios and fetching the details I'm trying to map the data but it is not working can anyone please help.

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import './cards.css'
import { API_KEY } from '../constants/constants'
import axios from '../../axios'

export default function Body() {
  const [video, setVideo] = useState()
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`videos?key=${API_KEY}&chart=mostPopular&part=snippet&maxResult=1&regionCode=IN`).then((response)=>{
      setVideo(response.data.items);
      console.log(response.data.items);
    })
  },[])
  return (
    
    <div className='main3'>
        <div className="thumb">
          {video.map((obj,index)=>
            <img key={`${obj.id}`} src={video ? video.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url : ''} alt="" />

          )}
        </div>
        <div className="ti">
          <p>{video ? video.snippet.title : ''}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="chimg">
          <p>c</p>
        </div>
        <div className="chtitle">
          <p>{video ? video.snippet.channelTitle : ''}</p>

        </div>
        
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: _"it is not working"_ isn't particularly useful to us. What debugging have you done? Are you actually getting data back from the API? Are there any errors in your console/network tabs in the dev tools? Is `video` actually an array?

Comment: Attach data that you get in result.

Comment: `key={`${obj.id}`}` this is unnecessary, instead use `key={obj.id}`

Comment: In the `video.map` you are not using the `obj` in `video.snippet...` don't you need to use `obj.video.snippet...`?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can define this way to handle errors of data types:

   const [video, setVideo] = useState([]);
2. Optional Chaining for handling map function error:

   ```
      {video?.map((obj,index)=>
    <img key={`${obj.id}`} src={video ? 
     video.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url : ''} alt="" />

     )}
   ```

Comment: This won't help if `video` isn't an array.

Comment: I added the default type of state as an array. Also, suggest adding optional chaining.

Comment: Yes, but the data being added to the `video` state might not be an array. You may be right but since the OP hasn't done any debugging we don't really know.